# What is the modern replacement for Tauberian Theorems?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

One strategy for proving the Prime Number Theorem is to use the results of Wiener and Ikehara.  In fact, he gives two different proofs using slightly different result.

> Them **220** If $g$ is $W$ and $h$ is $L$ and $f$ is bounded then $P_g(f) \to P_h(f)$.  In other words:
>   $$ \left[\int g(x-t) f(t) \, dt \to l \int f(t) \, dt \right] \to \left[\int h(x-t) f(t) \, dt \to l \int f(t) \, dt \right] $$

This statement (from Hardy's [Divergent Series](https://archive.org/details/DivergentSeries)) look oddly vacuous and not related to divergent series.  As best I could tell:

- $\widehat{g}(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
- $h \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$
- $ |f(x)| < M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. bounded)

I guess the theorem is that any $L^1$ function over the real line can be spanned by translates of a single function whose Fourier transform is nowhere vanishing on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Many things have bothered me about this statement:

- Could this be a generalization of Karamata Tauberian theorem?  That can also be phrased as showing all continuous functions are within the span of translates of  single function.
- How is this related to the non-vanishing of the zeta function on the line $\zeta(1 + it) \neq 0$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ ?
- Tauberian theorems are dismissed by some analysts as a novelty.  What could be the modern replacement?

For the last question I found this result in a textbook [[1](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319324098)]:

> A function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous iff 
>   it is differentiable a.e., if $f'$ is locally integrable and for all $a,x \in [0,1]$ we have $$f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) \, dt $$

Penot's textbook teaches functional analysis in analogy with convex geometry, even if it's not too visual.

---

**Historical Aside** In response to Todd Trimble's comment, the Hardy's book on divergent series was published in 1949, two years after his death.

[image]

Comment: Some text seems to have disappeared or be replaced by a horizontal line. "I guess the theorem is that any $L^1$ function over the real line can be spanned by translates of a single function that". That what? The suspense is killing me... (Also: who is 'he' in the first line? Hardy?)

Comment: @Vincent corrected.  I'm also looking at Norbert Weiner's original 1932 paper on [Tauberian Theorems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968102) but it's much  harder to read.  Hardy wrote his text 40 years later.

Comment: Thank you! I hope you get an answer, because I  find the statement quite  unreadable. Do all the occurences of $\to$ in the statement have the same meaning, or are some convergence, some indicating a function and some a logical implication?

Comment: The last sentence of the post is missing (at least) a verb. Also, re "Hardy wrote his text 40 years later" (i.e. 1972/3) -- Hardy died in 1947.

Comment: @Vincent I mad sure to use Hardy's own language.  Just so you can see.  The middle arrow just means "implies" while the ones on the left and the right are limits of some kind.

Comment: Ugh that is horrible

Comment: Ehm to be clear: in my last remark I meant Hardy's notation, not yours

Comment: @Vincent instead of $\to$ should I just write "implies" ?  I think in the modern "functorial" era, I could read these Tauberian theorems as a relationship between two different limits.  I heard these are considered quite old-fashioned by analysts, but what would they replace it with?

Comment: Well yes, for me that would make the statement much clearer. As for your actual question I have no idea.